# Ctrl+Arrows work differently in normal mode and in insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, normal-mode, insert-mode

For some reason, in my VIM there is a difference in behaviour of Ctrl+Arrow keys in normal mode and in insert mode. To demonstrate this, I edit the file which contents are:

```
aaa.aaa,aaa/aaa!aaa@aaa#aaa$aaa%aaa^aaa&aaa aaa*aaa(aaa)aaa{aaa}aaa[aaa]aaa-aaa=aaa_aaa"aaa'aaa
```

In insert mode, when I press Ctrl+Right key, here is where the cursor stops:

`a`aa`.a`aa,aaa`/a`aa`!a`aa`@a`aa`#a`aa`$a`aa`%a`aa`^a`aa`&a`aa aa`a*`aaa`(a`aa`)a`aa`{a`aa`}a`aa`[a`aa`]a`aa`-a`aa`=a`aa`_a`aa`"a`aa`'a`aa

In normal mode, here is where the cursor stops:

`a`aa.aaa,aaa/aaa!aaa@aaa#aaa$aaa%aaa^aaa&aaa `a`aa*aaa(aaa)aaa{aaa}aaa[aaa]aaa-aaa=aaa_aaa"aaa'aaa

I'd like to make it work in normal mode just like it currently works in insert mode.

What I know so far is that `:map` and `:map!` don't contain any maps for Ctrl+Arrows keys.
Also, VIM recognises Ctrl+Arrows sequences right, i checked that by doing

```
:nmap <C-Right> :echo 'Normal mode Ctrl+Right'<CR>
:imap <C-Right> <ESC>:echo 'Insert mode Ctrl+Right'<CR>
```

And I see the effect when I try pressing Ctrl+Arrows
How can I fix this?

Update: I've tried the same with a new user who has no ~/.vimrc or ~/.vim, and it reproduces
Update2: I'm not remapping the  key either

Comment: FWIW I can reproduce this behavior with neovim but not with vim. It might be worth checking if it's part of a new config in neovim.

Comment: I think the difference is basically `w` (insertmode) vs `W` in normal mode and this seems to be an inconsistency in the source. In edit.c `fwd_word()` is called and in normal mode `nv_wordcmd()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK looks like @ChristianBrabandt is right.
The answer is,

```
:nmap <C-Left> b
:nmap <C-Right> w
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim!. If you build your answer from comments left by others we encourage you to post it as a community answer (or ask the author of the comment to post an answer himself).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt sure, how do I post an answer as a community answer?

Comment: I believe there is check box for that at the bottom of the editing screen.